# Gravity form : No display when conditional logic, even with wp_footer() and with jQuery downloaded in section

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

The subject should be clear enough. On this page : https://www.archionline.com/test-form-one-page/ we are supposed to have a conditional gravity form.

It is not displayed, so I searched online for solutions (FAQ, forums and such), and I can’t find any.

Know that we have in footer.php :

```
<?php wp_footer() ?>
```

And jQuery installed and downloaded before GravityForm.

Also, I don’t want to change our version of jQuery as I don’t know what else it could impact.

Thank you !

**EDIT :** 
It seems that the problem could occur if jQuery is loaded twice.
How can I prevent GravityForm to load jQuery ?

Comment: Your form is definitely rendered on the page but hidden. Can you let me know what conditions have you set? What are the form settings?

Comment: Hey, true that it is rendered but display:none.
i understand that it hides the form until the page is loaded, and then apply Gravity JS to display part of it (conditional form).

Anyway, the form should display certain fields depending on choice on the first field.

About the settings, it is all defaults, except for the form class : "gform_wrapper" and the button text : "Recevoir mon estimation". Of course the conditions are activated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching, this is what worked for me.

Adding :

```
add_filter("gform_init_scripts_footer", "init_scripts");
function init_scripts() {
  return true;
}
```

in functions.php.

Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: from gravity forms site, this is shorter version that does the same thing:
`add_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', '__return_true' );`